# Docompose tag by its content/text

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to decompose h4 tag which having photos or prototypes text/content.

Here is HTML code

```
     <div class='wrap'>
       <div class='col'>
          <h4 class='h4'>photos</h4>
          <h4 class='h4'>videos</h4>
           <h4 class='h4'>prototypes</h4>
            <h4 class='h4'>weight</h4>
        </div>
      <div class='col'>
          <h4 class='h4'>color</h4>
           <h4 class='h4'>selfie</h4>
            <h4 class='h4'>front</h4>
             <h4 class='h4'>back</h4>
       </div>
       </div>
```

and output I want:

```
<div class='wrap'>
       <div class='col'>
          <h4 class='h4'>videos</h4>
            <h4 class='h4'>weight</h4>
        </div>
      <div class='col'>
          <h4 class='h4'>color</h4>
           <h4 class='h4'>selfie</h4>
            <h4 class='h4'>front</h4>
             <h4 class='h4'>back</h4>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass [a regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)  to the `text` parameter in `find_all`. Then [decompose](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) each tag that matches.

```
html_doc="""
<div class='wrap'>
   <div class='col'>
      <h4 class='h4'>photos</h4>
      <h4 class='h4'>videos</h4>
       <h4 class='h4'>prototypes</h4>
        <h4 class='h4'>weight</h4>
    </div>
  <div class='col'>
      <h4 class='h4'>color</h4>
       <h4 class='h4'>selfie</h4>
        <h4 class='h4'>front</h4>
         <h4 class='h4'>back</h4>
   </div>
</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('h4',text=re.compile('photos|prototypes')):
    tag.decompose()
print(soup)
```

Output

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="col">

<h4 class="h4">videos</h4>

<h4 class="h4">weight</h4>
</div>
<div class="col">
<h4 class="h4">color</h4>
<h4 class="h4">selfie</h4>
<h4 class="h4">front</h4>
<h4 class="h4">back</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Python `lambda` function to find `tag` and their `text` and then decompose().

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<div class='wrap'>
       <div class='col'>
          <h4 class='h4'>photos</h4>
          <h4 class='h4'>videos</h4>
           <h4 class='h4'>prototypes</h4>
            <h4 class='h4'>weight</h4>
        </div>
      <div class='col'>
          <h4 class='h4'>color</h4>
           <h4 class='h4'>selfie</h4>
            <h4 class='h4'>front</h4>
             <h4 class='h4'>back</h4>
       </div>
       </div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all(lambda tag:tag.name=='h4' and ('photos' in tag.text or 'prototypes' in tag.text) ):
    item.decompose()

print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="col">

<h4 class="h4">videos</h4>

<h4 class="h4">weight</h4>
</div>
<div class="col">
<h4 class="h4">color</h4>
<h4 class="h4">selfie</h4>
<h4 class="h4">front</h4>
<h4 class="h4">back</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @souravkukreti : Great.Happy to help you.Can you accept that answer by clicking on holo under downvote button and UP vote as well if you think that will help future followers.